# Remove unwanted items from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm parsing a csv in my node script using csv-parser npm module. I need to remove the first entry and the empty entry of each object that is returned from the parser. At the moment I have this code that will push the parsed csv data into an array:

```js
const parser = require('csv-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const csvFile = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'LottoData.csv'}); 
const parsedData = [];

fs.createReadStream(csvFile)
.pipe(parser({ separator: ';', headers: false}))
.on('data', (data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    parsedData.push(data);
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log(parsedData);
});
```

The csv parser will return an object wit hthis structure when data are processed:

```
  {
    '0': '23/03/1940',
    '1': '12',
    '2': '10',
    '3': '12',
    '4': '19',
    '5': '23',
    '6': '28',
    '7': '29',
    '8': '31',
    '9': '39',
    '10': '44',
    '11': '50',
    '12': '51',
    '13': '53',
    '14': '54',
    '15': '56',
    '16': '62',
    '17': '64',
    '18': '65',
    '19': '68',
    '20': '71',
    '21': '80',
    '22': '28',
    '23': ''
  },
```

How I can remove the date and the empty items from each returned object and pass each single value into an array directly instead of pushing the entire object?

Comment: checkout `Object.entries()`

Comment: `Object.values(parsedData).filter(x => x && !Number.isNaN(Number(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the object's list of values into an array, and then filter out anything that isn't what you want:

```
const filtered = Object.values(parsedData).filter(v => isValidData(v)});
```

Where you get to implement the `isValidData` function yourself, based on what you know about your data.

(Looking at what you're showing it *seems* to be "`v` should be number" so if that's the case, that should be trivial to implement for you)